# Puzzled by lists in command line

Tags: linux, bash, list

I encountered something like this today.

```
lst=(1 2 3 4)
echo $lst
```

prints

```
1
```

After sometime I did this

```
lst=(1,2,3,4)
echo $lst
```

and correctly got `1,2,3,4`

Why does it behave like this? I don't know for sure what is going on here, but I believe that it has something to do with the spaces in the original `lst=(1 2 3 4)`

But what I want to know is, why does it make a difference if we use commas instead of spaces?

Comment: Shell arrays are space delimited not comma delimited. Your first example is a shell array of four elements. Your second example is an array of one element. Compare the output of `declare -p lst` for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why does `lst=(1 2 3 4); echo $lst` print `1`?

Because you've made `lst` an array of four elements. If you reference an array variable without a subscript, `bash` uses the element with subscript 0, as though you had entered `echo ${lst[0]}`

### Why is `lst=(1,2,3,4)` different?

Because in an array assignment, the elements are produced by normal word-splitting, which occurs on white space. Commas are not special, so `lst=(1,2,3,4)` makes `lst` into an array variable with 1 element (whose subscript is 0).

### How do I see all the elements of an array?

Like this:

```
echo "${lst[@]}"
```